# Disabling IPV6 leads to default route being lost on reboot

Tags: networking

I have a new dedicated server from Heztner. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (minimal).

I have a problem which results in the default route being lost on reboot, killing all connectivity to the server.

Prior to the problem occuring, executing "route -n" outputs the following:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         xxx.xx.xxx.xxx  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp2s0
```

After it occurs (and I get access to the terminal via KVM), this returns:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
```

I have recreated this 3 times following fresh installs of the OS and have now tied the issue to the following settings that I am applying to sysctl.conf to disable IPV6:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

My netplan config is as follows (nameservers also listed after what I am showing here - both ipv4 and ipv6):

```
### Hetzner Online GmbH installimage
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      addresses:
        - <ipv4 ip here>
        - <ipv6 ip here>
      routes:
        - on-link: true
          to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: <ipv4 ip here>
      gateway6: fe80::1
```

I checked with Heztner and they are not aware of any reason why disabling IPV6 would be problematic.